# Bitbucket pipelines Webpack -> FTP. No files after build to upload to the server. Artifacts doesn't work

Tags: webpack, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, git-ftp

I am building my Webpack by bitbucket pipelines by pushing commit to the production branch:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test JS.
        image: node:8.9.3
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
          - npm run-script build
    - step:
        name: Build and test PHP.
        image: php:7-fpm
        script:
          - echo "Here will be the Composer build and PHPUnit tests."          
  branches:
    production:
    - step:
        name: Build and test JS.
        image: node:8.9.3
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
          - npm run-script build
        artifacts:
          - dist/**
    - step:
        name: Build and test PHP.
        image: php:7-fpm
        script:
          - echo "Here will be the Composer build and PHPUnit tests."  
        artifacts:
          - dist/**
    - step:
        name: Deploy to FTP.
        image: samueldebruyn/debian-git
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - ls public_html
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_HOST
```

I see that webpack build is fine but files does not go to the next step. After that production build I should have output public_html/js and public_html/css and index.html files that should be available in next step that is git ftp. After "ls public_html" command there are no such files in that directory. I also use .gitignore and .git-ftp-ignore (I allow there my js, css, index.html files).

What is going on and how can i fix that? Please for help.

> UPDATE: After listing public_html after npm build I can see build
> files! So the only problem is to 'send' them to the next step.
>
> UPDATE2: I think the problem is that ftp-git is not sending artifacts to the
> server even when I use .git-ftp-include. Last "ls public_html" shows all build files.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: My "dist/**" at pipelines was wrong because I was building app in webpack to  "public_html"

Comment: So.... do you have it working now, if so, what is the solution?

Comment: Please add solution, I am still figuring out

Comment: @Sanuj webpack was configured to build files to `public_html/*` directory but `dist/*` directory was listed in artifacts. this caused pipelines to move (empty/non existing) `dist/*`  directory to next pipeline step and discard  `public_html/*` directory. Add `public_html/*` to artifacts to solve this issue